# Is it possible to reproduce non-compositional queues example in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, composition, java-memory-model, jls

I'm reading The Art of Multiprocessor Programming, 2nd ed.
Sequential consistency is defined there this way:

> Sequential consistency requires that method calls act as if they occurred in a sequential order consistent with program order.

It's noted that sequential consistency need not preserve the real-time order, as demonstrated by this example:

> ```
>        q.enq(x)         q.deq(y)
> A  ...=========........=========......>
>
>                     q.enq(y)
> B  ................=========..........>
> ```
>
> **FIGURE 3.7**
> *Sequential consistency versus real-time order. Thread A enqueues x, and later thread B enqueues y, and finally A dequeues y. This execution may violate our intuitive notion of how a FIFO queue should behave because the method call enqueuing x finishes before the method call enqueuing y starts, so y is enqueued after x. But it is dequeued before x. Nevertheless, this execution is sequentially consistent.*

And finally the book says that sequential consistency is not composable:

> Is sequential consistency compositional? That is, is the result of composing multiple sequentially consistent objects itself sequentially consistent? The answer, unfortunately, is no. In Fig. 3.8, two threads, *A* and *B*, call enqueue and dequeue methods for two queue objects, *p* and *q*. It is not hard to see that *p* and *q* are each sequentially consistent: The sequence of method calls for *p* is the same as in the sequentially consistent execution shown in Fig. 3.7, and the behavior of *q* is symmetric. Nevertheless, the execution as a whole is not sequentially consistent.
>
> ```
>      p.enq(x)     q.enq(x)    p.deq(y)
> A  ..=======......=======.....=======..........>
>
>            q.enq(y)     p.enq(y)    q.deq(x)
> B  ........=======......=======.....=======....>
> ```
>
> **FIGURE 3.8**
> *Sequential consistency is not compositional. Two threads, A and B, call enqueue and dequeue methods on two queue objects, p and q. It is not hard to see that p and q are each sequentially consistent, yet the execution as a whole is not sequentially consistent.*
>
> To see that there is no correct sequential execution of these methods calls that is consistent with their program order, assume, by way of contradiction, that there is such an execution. We use the following shorthand: `⟨p.enq(x) A⟩ → ⟨p.deq()x B⟩` means that any sequential execution must order A’s enqueue of x at p before *B*’s dequeue of *x* at *p*, and so on. Because *p* is FIFO and *A* dequeues *y* from *p*, *y* must have been enqueued at *p* before *x*:
>     `⟨p.enq(y) B⟩ → ⟨p.enq(x) A⟩`.
> Similarly, *x* must have been enqueued onto *q* before *y*:
>     `⟨q.enq(x) A⟩ → ⟨q.enq(y) B⟩`.
> But program order implies that
>     `⟨p.enq(x) A⟩ → ⟨q.enq(x) A⟩` and `⟨q.enq(y) B⟩ → ⟨p.enq(y) B⟩`.
> Together, these orderings form a cycle.

Java Language Specification has this in [Chapter 17.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3):

> If a program has no data races, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent.

**My question: Is the situation in Fig. 3.8 above possible in a multithreaded data-race-free Java program?**

Also, maybe it's only possible for some concurrent queue implementations.
In this case it would be great to find out which queues from [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) are composable and which aren't, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **My question: Is the situation in Fig. 3.8 above possible in a multithreaded data-race-free Java program?**

No.  Your JLS quote is analytical, not aspirational:

> If a program has no data races, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent.

However, the JLS's definition of sequential consistency is different from your book's.  The book is apparently defining the term with respect to individual objects (queues, in its examples) whereas Java defines the same term (only) with respect to whole program executions and programs' whole memory.  With Java's definition, the book's "p and q are each sequentially consistent" is nonsensical.

It follows that if you observed behavior such as is depicted in the book's Figure 3.8 in a Java program, then that would be symptomatic of a data race.  Indeed, I would say that the same applies to programs in *any* language, provided that you apply Java's definitions of terms.

> Also, maybe it's only possible for some concurrent queue implementations.
> In this case it would be great to find out which queues from java.util.concurrent are composable and which aren't, and why.

If it were possible for any of the queue implementations in `java.util.concurrent` then that would constitute a bug in those implementations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
A small additional question: what if we had several java processes which communicate without delays (e.g. over `localhost` network interface), would the situation on Fig. 3.8 be possible?

Comment: @user19858110, generally speaking, sequential consistency and data races are about operations on shared memory.  Programs that communicate only via network messages do not share memory, so the concepts do not apply directly to combinations of those.  Whether you could observe behavior analogous to figure 3.8 is a question of implementation details that you have not described.

Comment: For example, consider this implementation: 1) thread A and thread B are two threads in a single java process 2) queue `p` is encapsulated in its own java process (e.g. microservice), methods `p.enq()` and `p.deq()` are invoked via HTTP request 3) queue `q` (just like `p`) has its own  java process 4) communication between processes is instantaneous (i.e. let's not  take into account network delay). Would it be possible to see in Thread A and Thread B behavior like in Fig. 3.8?

Comment: In other words: will the java queues in this case be visible to external processes as sequentially consistent objects, and, as a result, the behavior in Fig 3.8 will become possible?

Comment: Again, @user19858110, it depends on implementation details. If you want to pursue this variation on your question then you should pose it as its own, separate question.